# Get Value Of File Input for Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've been using JQuery validation for all of my forms on my website but I've just started on an upload script for image files and it's not validating correctly. Here is the code that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var avatarok = 0;
//Post Avatar
$('#avatar').blur(function()
{
var avatar=$("#avatar").val();
if(avatar.length < 1){
    avatarok = 0;
}
else{
    avatarok = 1;
}
});
// Submit button action
$('#avatarButton').click(function()
{
if(avatarok == 1)
{           
    $('.avatarValidation').addClass("sending");
    $("#avatarForm").submit();
}
else
{
$('.avatarValidation').addClass("validationError");
}
return false;
});
//End
});
```

When I click on the button (avatarButton) it always shows the error class, even if a file has been selected. Any theories?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that uploads or GETs anything. Where is that code?

Comment: What do you mean exactly @KevinB? I've used the same style of coding for all of my other forms and they work fine?

Comment: Sorry, i miss-read your code. please disregard.

Comment: @KevinB Ah right, So can you see a possible solution? This same coding has worked on other forms so technically should work the same

Comment: your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn6p7/ you sure you don't have some other element on your page with an `id="avatar"`?

Comment: Yeah thanks @KevinB, I had another #avatar in a hidden field to unlink the old file. Sorted now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
check the below solution and blur condition not executing so that u are getting same message
// Submit button action
$('#avatarButton').click(function()
{
    var avatar=$("#avatar").val();

if(avatar == 1)
{           
    $('.avatarValidation').addClass("sending");
    $("#avatarForm").submit();

}
else
{
$('.avatarValidation').addClass("validationError");

}
return false;
});

//End
and remove your blur function no use
```